# How to fix "No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)"?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to send an HTTP post request, everything was fine so far (I sent 10+ requests in this application), but now there is a problem.

I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)
```

This is the interface code:

```
@POST("index.php/web/request")
    Call<MyResponse> getMy(@Header("authorization") String token, MyRequest myRequest);
```

This is my MainActivity code:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://link.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        service = retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);

        MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest();

        myRequest.setText(text);

        final Call<MyResponse> myResponseCall = service.getMy(token, myRequest);
```

Error is in this line:

```
final Call<MyResponse> myResponseCall = service.getMy(token, myRequest);
```

Comment: @DeepakS.Gavkar I have not changed anything since my last request, I don't know exactly what you think...

Comment: you have not annotated the second parameter.... it can be @Body,@Query etc.... add an annotation

Comment: @Kushan that's it, thanks!

Comment: great added it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have not annotated the second parameter.... it can be @Body,@Query etc.... add an annotation

Answer (score 0):

change your interface method to this

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("index.php/web/request")
    Call<MyResponse> getMy(@Header("authorization") String token);
```

or

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("index.php/web/request")
        Call<MyResponse> getMy(@Header("authorization") String token, MyRequest myRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Body or use @Filed("name_parameter")
and above the method put  @FormUrlEncoded.